# pip upgrade issue using python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

Recently, I've been trying to upgrade my pip using the following command:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

the process goes as follows:

```
Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 1.7 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.3
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
```

Then a bunch of `Moving to` lines start to appear, then comes the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
```

What am I suppossed to do ???

Answer (score 6):

This is likely an issue with the `pip` installation. You can fix it using the following steps:

1. Uninstall the current pip:

   ```
   python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
   ```
2. Download `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
3. Run the get-pip script:

   ```
   python get-pip.py
   ```

Alternatively you can use, but it isn't recommended:

```
easy install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I uninstalled pip as above and then ran a version check to verify:

```
python -m pip --version
```

and got

```
pip 21.0.1 from C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

Finding that odd, I reran the upgraded again:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and got

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (21.0.1)
```

I realize that this was being performed from user account.  So, I re-did the upgrade as an Administrator. This time there was no "Defaulting ..." line.

It seems that if you're not careful when installing/upgrading pip you can inadvertently change it's availability from global to user-specific, borking the removal process for future upgrades.

TL;DR As Administrator, after upgrading to pip 21.0.1, uninstall pip (python -m pip uninstall) to fix the "ValueError".

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall setup tools using this command:

```bash
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

Install setup tools again using this command:

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```